# On-behalf-of on Azure Ad v2.0 endpoint for both MSA (Microsoft personal) and AAD accounts

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-msal

We have a user-facing web app and a middle-tier ASP.NET Core Web api, currently using OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) on the Azure Ad v1.0 endpoint, authenticating only AAD accounts. We need to authenticate also MSA (personal) accounts, therefore migrate our solution to the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.

The [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph) only authenticates AAD accounts and says:

> "**Current limitations**:
>   The on-behalf-of flow does not currently work for Microsoft Personal accounts."

Can somebody confirm this ? 
What is the alternative for getting a service to service token for both Microsoft Personal accounts and work or school accounts if this is the case?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, it seems MSA does not support combined consent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#default-and-combined-consent. But that alone does not mean OBO does not work.

Comment: I totally agree that shouldn’t mean it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, a common OBO pattern cannot be used for clients that sign in both personal and work or school accounts. The general guidelines recommend, if possible, to merge the middle tier application and the front-end UI into one AAD v2.0 application. Ofcourse, this can only be done if you have a single front-end mapped to the middle tier and won't be applicable in cases of multiple front-ends sharing the same middle tier.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#consent-for-azure-ad--microsoft-account-applications) provides information regarding the reasons for these limitations and the workaround that I described above. Unfortunately, merging the two applications is the only way.

Comment: i had already read the MSDN documentation , and « a common OBO pattern cannot be used » isn’t the same as « obo flow doesn’t currently work for Microsoft personal accounts » in my opinion. I’d appreciate if you could share any additional insights other than what’s already written in MSDN.

Comment: Also just wanted to double check if I'm getting this correctly: by "merging into one AAD v2.0 application" do you mean "using the same app registration" from both front-end & middle-tier?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by merging, you can have one app registered in Azure Portal to represent both front-end and middle tier.

Comment: As an alternative, if you do not absolutely have to use any specific delegated permission or user claim in the back-end service, you could go ahead with Client Credentials grant flow between the middle-tier component and the back-end service. Essentially, the auth between UI and user would be user-based and the auth between middle-tier and back-end would be service-principal based. Without knowing the complete scenario, its difficult to recommend any approach.

Comment: We do have to use delegated permissions on the middle-tier to be able to make calls on behalf of the authenticated user to the downstream APIs. And I’d already interpreted the documentation the same as you did, that the recommended strategy is sharing a single app registration between front-end and middle tier but couldn’t get this work with Tenant: common (msa+aad). And the sample says « don’t use common setting for tenant, see limitations » and limitations say « it doesn’t work for personal accounts » this whole thing is very confusing and wanted to clarify it before wasting more time

Comment: The common tenant is a problem if you are using the OBO flow. For standard authorization code grant flow (in case of ASP.NET front end) and implicit flow (in case of SPA front end), the common tenant should work (although you might have to give up validating the token issuer). If you are considering the option of using a single registered app, please look at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes-on-web-apps (check examples at bottom) for ASP.NET front end

Comment: For SPA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa. To answer your question about direct support for OBO flow for MSA + AAD accounts, there is a solution but its Microsoft Internal so unfortunately won't work for you at the moment.

Comment: The solution you've shared calls Microsoft Graph directly from SPA. Which is clearly not what I'm trying to achieve. I have a whole middle-tier which our SPA interacts and which I cannot abandon. By Microsoft internal you mean internal team & 1st party (I guess not because the only option is dual-stacking for those)? Could you give some more hints for the internal+3rd party approach?

Comment: (also thanks for the previous samples but my SPA is reactjs based and uses msal.js - has not .net dependencies.)

Comment: Yes I mean first party apps owned by Microsoft and Partners. All of those mechanisms rely on RPS (Relying Party SDK) to break the MSA compact ticket (Access token) from the user and generate converted tickets to be passed to the downstream services. Unfortunately, for MSA logins there is no publicly available support for OBO flow.

Comment: feel free to reply [here](https://stackoverflow.microsoft.com/questions/139987/is-on-behalf-of-flow-supported-on-azure-ad-v2-0-for-microsoft-personal-accounts/140075#140075)

Answer (score 0):

On-behalf-of flow with MSA is now supported.

Please check [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/3.-Web-api-call-Microsoft-graph-for-personal-accounts) for more details.